# Pandas - How do add values to fields based on another string value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a check on a string, and if that string is equal to a condition, do something, otherwise do something else.

As now I can't get how you accomplish this, since I can't use `where` because my value is a string and not a number.

Imagine a field with a string like this for each entry:

```
abcde test1 12345 AAA
abcde test2 12345 
abcde test3 12345 AAA
abcde test4 12345 AAA
```

I want to put in a field called "joint", the values "abcde" and "test1" if the 4th value is "AAA", otherwise I want to add just "abcde".

I can split the value in the field, so I can get to "AAA" with

`df['compositestring'].str.split(' ').str[3]`

But how do I tell pandas to do something like this, for every value in the dataset?

```
if df['compositestring'].str.split(' ').str[3] == "AAA":
    df['joint'] = df['compositestring'].str.split(' ').str[0]
else:
    df['joint'] = df['compositestring'].str.split(' ').str[0] + " " + df['compositestring'].str.split(' ').str[1]
```

So I can get as output, something like this, in a field called "joint"

```
joint

abcde test1
abcde 
abcde test3
abcde test4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use boolean mask `m` with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
splitted = df['compositestring'].str.split()
m = splitted.str[3] == "AAA"
a = splitted.str[0]
b = a + " " + splitted.str[1]

df['joint'] = np.where(m, b, a)
print (df)

         compositestring        joint
0  abcde test1 12345 AAA  abcde test1
1     abcde test2 12345         abcde
2  abcde test3 12345 AAA  abcde test3
3  abcde test4 12345 AAA  abcde test4
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! BTW I made a mistake writing the question; the joint and results are the same field; I did change the question to reflect the error. Sorry about that

Comment: Rectified the question, adding the example of the string in the field "compositestring" and the output I am trying to obtain, in the "joint" field

Comment: I see, so I can use `np.where`, even if the values are not numerals; Thanks!